# Solr error - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (null)

Tags: c#, solr, http-headers, solrnet

When sending long queries to solr like this:

> q=(CC%3a((1)+ ... +(n)))&rows=100000000&fl=CP

I am constantly getting this message:

> 400 Bad request message.

When I investigated further using fiddler I am actually getting:

> the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (null)

When I reduce the number of parameters this query works, but when I increase to a certain limit I get the above error.

Earlier I was using GET solr queries and I increased the `maxHttpHeaderSize` but I still get the same result. I then used POST solr queries, increased the `maxPostSize` and it also gave the same result.

Can someone help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: POST should work, it has no limit. However, ask yourself *why* you need such a long query (my guess is, you're using Solr the wrong way).

Comment: I agree. But currently our priority is just to make the existing design work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix.
Just increase the **Maximum number of clauses in each BooleanQuery** parameter

```
../conf/solrconfig.xml
<maxBooleanClauses>134217728</maxBooleanClauses>
```